# Unable to read external storage in Xamarin.Forms for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, permissions, android-external-storage

In the Xamarin.Forms application we are developing, called "myApp", targeting Android devices only, we need to be able to read from (and possibly write to) the text file

```
storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.configuration/myAppStuff.txt
```

which in the Windows 10 development platform appears as

```
This PC\DEVICE TYPE\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.myApp.configuration\
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file for the project, we have included

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
</manifest>
```

This is confirmed in Visual Studio 2022 by navigating to

```
Project > myApp.Android Properties > Android Manifest > Required permissions:
```

and observing the required permissions are asserted.

When the application is first started in the debug mode, in MainActivity.cs

```
AndroidX.Core.App.ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)
```

returns "false", so we invoke

```
AndroidX.Core.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Android.Manifest.Permission.ManageExternalStorage }, 0)
```

Android shows a (non-modal) dialog

[image: dialog]

for which we select "ALLOW".

Later, the code

```
File.Exists("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.configuration/myAppStuff.txt")
```

returns "true"

but the code

```
mystreamreader = new StreamReader("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.configuration/myAppStuff.txt");
```

throws the exception with Message value of

```
"Access to the path \"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp.configuration/myAppStuff.txt\" is denied."
```

A later check shows that the code

```
AndroidX.Core.App.ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ManageExternalStorage)
```

returns the value "false".

Why?

Comment: what version are you targeting?  Storage permissions have involved a LOT from version to version

Comment: You do not need any permission for that app specific directory. Well if it is the app specific directory of your app.

Comment: Besides File.exists() also use File.canRead() before you try to read from other locations.

Comment: `Unable to read external storage ....` Well that is not a good description. Better: `Unable to read from app specific directory..`

Comment: Version is 10 API 29.  Also, this issue happens regardless of the folder name used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. But you said:

> we need to be able to read from (and possibly write to) the text file

So I created a sample to read and write the text file:

In my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
              package="com.companyname.app21">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="App21.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Please make sure the package's value in your AndroidManifest.xml file is `com.myApp.configuration`.

And the code about create, read and write the file:

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app21/test.txt",
                                                     FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                     FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                                     FileShare.ReadWrite); 
// create the text file     
File.WriteAllText("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app21/test.txt", "this is content");
// write the text file
var content = File.ReadAllText("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app21/test.txt");
//read the text file
```

Comment: Liyun: Thank you for your continued help. 

If the folder does not exist on the device, the new FileStream code you recommend throws the exception

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Message=Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app21/test.txt".

If the folder already exists on the device, the new FileStream code you recommend throws the exception

System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Message=Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app21/test.txt" is denied.

Comment: The `com.companyname.app21` is my application's package name. You need change it as your app's package name. Please check the `<manifest .... package="com.xxx.xxx">` value in your AndroidManifest.xml. @DumbestGuyOnSaturn

Comment: Finally.  That works.  So how do we access folders that do not have that exact name?  Possibly there are other items that have to be included in the AndroidManifest.xml?  And thanks!

Comment: What does the folders that do not have that exact name mean? Can you provide an example? The folder now used is the app's private folder. @DumbestGuyOnSaturn

Comment: Lihun: For example, a folder with the name com.appname.configuration.

Comment: That folder seems not belong to your app. You has no permission to access it. @DumbestGuyOnSaturn

Answer (score 1):

Which Android version? As of Android13, EXTERNAL_STORAGE is basically gone. CheckSelfPermission for it will auto-answer false, just as if you answered "No and do not ask again" before. They want you to move to different APIs, e.g. ask a Document Picker to get arbitrary files or be a Document Provider to provide them.

Comment: Version is 10 API 29.